# Hair spray on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hair, boneh-soter

According to Halacha, is it permissible to spray your hair with spray on Shabbat? Or would this fall under a form of prohibited melacha on Shabbat, potentially Boneh?

If not, is there anything problematic with brushing it after it’s been sprayed with the hair spray regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shmirat Shabat kHilchata writes (14:50 in the English edition, 14:56 in the Hebrew)

> **It is forbidden to spray the hair** or a wig in order to stiffen it
> and preserve the coiffure.

as you wrote, this is because of the *melacha* of *boneh*. R Daniel Braude (Learn Shabbos, p. 298) writes this also applies to mousse or gel to keep the hair in place.

**Brushing hair is a different issue, forbidden because of *gozez*** (see [SA OC 303:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.303.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). See [MB 86](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.303.27?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.303.86&lang2=bi) which comes out quite strongly against those who are lenieng on this issue.